# Impossible to create a document in Mongodb with Mongoose and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem with Mangoose and NodeJS. I explain :

- I have a MongoDB "babyfootdb" and the connection with Mongoose is OK.
- Inside the DB, I have a collection named players.
  I just want to add a test document, a player (name, email, password) in the collection "players".

But it's not working, I haven't errors but the document isn't created.

Here's my code :

Server.js :

```
// Set up
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Connection
var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/babyfootdb');
connection.on("error", function(){
    console.log("Error");
});
connection.on("open", function(){
    console.log("Connected");
});

// Models
require("./models")(app);
```

In models.js :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(app){


    //Schema
    var playerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        mail : String,
        password: String,
    }, {collection : 'players'});

    //Model
    var Player = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);

    //Create
    Player.create({name : "test",mail : "test",password : "test"},
    function(){   
        Player.find(function(err, players){
            console.log("find");
            if(err) return console.error(err);
            console.log(players); 
        });
    });
}
```

Sorry for my bad English but Thanks in advance if you have an idea to help me.

Answer (score 1):

It' fixed. I replaced :

```
//Connection
var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/babyfootdb');
connection.on("error", function(){
    console.log("Error");
});
connection.on("open", function(){
    console.log("Connected");
});
```

By :

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bfdb');
mongoose.connection.on("error", function(){
    console.log("Error");
});
mongoose.connection.on("open", function(){
    console.log("Connected");   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're declaring your model as `Player`, try using `Player.create(documentToBeCreated)`. You also don't have a `pseudo` field defined in your Schema but you're trying to use it in `create()`, so that could cause some issues. A different way to create a doc would be: 
`new Player(docToBeCreated).save(callback(err, player))`. Let us know if this helps :)

Comment: Sorry it's my fault I have renamed Joueur to Player and Pseudo to Name to post here. 
I tried and it's the same problem with .save() :(

Comment: I just noticed this, but you may need to include the port when connecting to mongodb, like `mongodb://localhost:27017/babyfootdb`. 27017 is the standard port for mongodb when used locally.

To help with the troubleshooting, try downloading a GUI like [Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/install/)

Comment: Thanks. I try but it's change nothing, the connection is ok. 
I already use Compass, it's really the create and save functions that not working, the log inside the create function is not display in the console. I don't understand

Comment: Aha...try using `function(err, user) { console.log(err, user) }` for the callback in `create()`. Read more [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Comment: Thanks but the log doesn't appear :(